# Find the exact value of $\sin\left(\arcsin(0.5)+\arctan(-4)\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the exact value of $\sin\left(\arcsin(0.5)+\arctan(-4)\right)$

My calculator gives a decimal for $\arctan(-4)$ so I don't know what answer is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of the principal values of  $\arcsin,\arctan$

$\arcsin(0.5)=30^\circ$

and let $\arctan(-4)=\alpha\implies\tan\alpha=-4$ and $-\dfrac\pi2<\alpha<0$

$\implies\sec\alpha=+\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}$ (See [All Sin Tan Cos](http://www.mathymind.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule-in-trigonometry/) Rule)

Now, $\cos\alpha=\dfrac1{\sec\alpha}$ and $\sin\alpha=\dfrac{\tan\alpha}{\sec\alpha}$

Now apply $\sin(A+B)$ for $\sin(30^\circ+\alpha)$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sum rule to expand the sine.  That will give you $\sin(\arctan(-4))$ and $\cos (\arctan (-4))$  For each, imagine a right triangle with legs $1,4$.  The angle opposite the $4$ leg has tangent $4$.  What is the hypotenuse?  Then you can evaluate $\sin (\arctan (4))$ and $\cos (\arctan(4))$ exactly.  They will have some square roots, but you will have an exact result. This technique works for any trig(arctrig()) combination.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta = \arcsin\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.  Then $\theta$ is a first-quadrant angle.  Draw a right triangle in the first quadrant with opposite leg of length $1$ and hypotenuse of length $2$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem, the adjacent leg is $\sqrt{3}$.

Let $\varphi = \arctan(-4)$.  Then $\varphi$ is a fourth-quadrant angle.  Draw a right triangle with opposite leg of length $4$ and adjacent leg of length $1$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem, the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{17}$.

[image]

Then

$$\sin\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \arctan(-4)\right] = \sin(\theta + \varphi)$$

We will use the sum of angles formula

$$\sin(\theta + \varphi) = \sin\theta\cos\varphi + \cos\theta\sin\varphi$$

From the diagram, we can see that

\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & = \frac{1}{2} & \sin\varphi & = -\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \cos\varphi & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}
\end{align*}

Thus,

\begin{align*}
\sin(\theta + \varphi) & = \sin\theta\cos\varphi + \cos\theta\sin\varphi\\
                       & = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}\right)\\
                       & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{17}} - \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{17}}\\
                       & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{17}}(1 - 4\sqrt{3})\\
                       & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{17}}(1 - 4\sqrt{3})\\
                       & = \frac{\sqrt{17}}{34}(1 - 4\sqrt{3})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have done my arithmetic incorrectly, the exact answer is:
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{17}}\left(1-4\sqrt{3})\right)
$$